# How to make a Bash Function with parameters?

Tags: bash

I'm trying to write a bash function in `.bash_profile` with a parameter that will run a script on my `sql` and test it, but I get the following error when trying to invoke it:

```
$ sqltest() ~/Downloads/hw5-2.sql
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `~/Downloads/hw5-2.sql`
```

The parameter is the file path. What I have right now (also have tried `"$1"` w/o quotes):

```
sqltest() { java -cp h2-1.4.200.jar org.h2.tools.RunScript  -checkResults -url jdbc:h2:mem:test -script "$1" -continueOnError ; }
```

Comment: If that guess is wrong, I'd suggest running `set -x` to enable trace logging, reproducing the error, and *showing us how you did it* with a transcript including both the command you ran and the exact text that resulted (up to and including the error message itself; any trace logs that relate to printing your prompt or other such local hooks don't need to be included).

Comment: (BTW, `"$1"` inside quotes is correct).

Comment: I am running as `sqltest() ~/Downloads/hw5-2.sql`

Comment: Just run `sqltest ~/Downloads/hw5-2.sql`. The `()` is not part of the function name.

Comment: or maybe better to use `"$HOME"` since `~` does not expand in quotes, single or double.

Comment: ...and next time, make sure the question you're asking includes *everything needed to produce the error*.

Comment: @Jetchisel, the expansion is done before the function is started, so `~` works fine. It would be a problem if they were running `sqltest "~/Downloads/hw5-2.sql"`, but they aren't.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy ok.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thank you! `sqltest ~/Downloads/hw5-2.sql` without the `()` worked.

Comment: Glad to hear! To mark your question solved, click the checkbox by an answer (because this one was duplicative, I answered it "community wiki", so I don't get any points from answer acceptance or upvotes; it just has the effect of marking the question as successfully addressed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leave the parenthesis out of the function call; they're only part of *function definition* syntax:

```
sqltest ~/Downloads/hw5-2.sql
```